# WP7 Panorama items binding and adding other custom panorama items c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am running into an issue where i am using a panorama control and binding it to a datasource. But i still do want other custom items on another panorama items where i need a textblock, a grid and so on. So if i am adding it in the backend it doesnt show up those panorama items. It just shows the datasource binded items. Why is that so? Both of them should work out.

Can anybody help me with a solution for this.

Thank You.

Comment: Show us what you're doing. Don't just describe it.

Comment: Basically i am developing a wp7 app where i am showing some rss feeds on panorama control. So initially i want the first panorama item to be loaded dynamically via a datasource. So that part is fine and is working. But i want to create second panorama item in c# backend where i can add a textblock and link it to one of my app pages. So is there a way to achieve this in any way without affecting the first panorama item layout. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Anybody please help me solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: need some more information, but you could try using two seperate listboxes, bind their itemssource to your feed and bind textblock and link to their corresponding listboxes elements

Answer (score 0):

Since you're wanting to manually add PanoramaItems, I can think of two approaches:

1. Make sure your Panorama.ItemsSource is set to an ObservableCollection that is accessible in the code behind or viewmodel, and then add your new items to that ObservableCollection which should update the Panorama.
2. Don't databind the Panorama control's Items - just add items manually when you want them.

Either way, the Panorama's ItemTemplate gets evaluated when the items are added to the underlying collection, so using a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) will allow your code to determine which DataTemplate to apply when the new item is added without affecting the templates for previous items.

/chris